# Java pathfinding optimisation with threading

Tags: java, multithreading, artificial-intelligence, path-finding, a-star

I am currently working on the AI portion of a 2D game top down fighting which is built using slick. Currently I have an A Star Search which I use to allow the AI opponent to find the player however due to the size of the game space this can often be laggy, especially if the obstacles generated result in a long path between the initial position of the player and the AI. To try and reduce this I am currently using a thread which is passed the opponents current coordinates as well as a set of predicted coordinates for the AI. I do this by predicting a certain number of steps into the future in the hope that by the time the AI has reached the predicted coordinates the search thread has completed and I can then get the given moveset from this. Here is my path finding thread's code:

```
    public class pathFindingThread implements Runnable {

private ArrayList<int[]> allObstacles;
private Stack<String> currentMoveset;
private Player enemy;
private AIPlayer ai;
private float currentEnemyX;
private float currentEnemyY;
private Node start;
private int aiX;
private int aiY;

public pathFindingThread(Player player, int aiX, int aiY, ArrayList<int[]> obstacles) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.enemy = player;
    this.aiX = aiX;
    this.aiY = aiY;
    this.ai = ai;
    this.allObstacles = obstacles;
}

public Node[][] setObstacles(Node[][] nodeMap) {
    int count = 0;
    while (count < this.allObstacles.size()) {
        int[] coords = allObstacles.get(count);
        if ((coords[1] < Board.BOARDHEIGHT) && (coords[0] < Board.BOARDWIDTH)) {
            nodeMap[coords[0]][coords[1]].setObstacle(true);
            nodeMap[coords[0]][coords[1]].setHeuristic(10000);
        }
        count++;
    }
    return nodeMap;
}

@Override
public void run() {

        //System.out.println("Running");
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            AStarSearch search = new AStarSearch();
            Node start = new Node(aiX, aiY);
            Node end = new Node((int) enemy.getX(), (int) enemy.getY());
            Node[][] nodeMap = search.generateNodeMap(Board.BOARDWIDTH, Board.BOARDHEIGHT);
            setObstacles(nodeMap);
            this.start = start;
            this.currentMoveset = search.AStar(nodeMap, start, end);


}

public Stack<String> getMoveset(){
    return this.currentMoveset;
}
```

Whilst this is how it is initialised in the main thread:

```
    public void moveSetUpdate(int aiX, int aiY) {
    UpdateMoveset newMoveset = new UpdateMoveset(enemy, aiX, aiY, this.allObstacles);
    if (isDone) {
        System.out.println("Running");
        thread = new pathFindingThread(enemy, aiX, aiY, this.allObstacles);
        Thread pathFinding = new Thread(thread);
        pathFinding.start();
        isDone = false;
    }
```

And finally how the current moveset is updated if the thread completes;

```
        if (this.isDone == false) {
        Stack<String> tempMoveset = new Stack<String>();
        Stack<String> finalMoveset = new Stack<String>();
        finalMoveset = thread.getMoveset();
        if (finalMoveset != null) {
            this.isDone = true;
        }
        if (this.isDone == true) {
            // System.out.println("The Moveset " + finalMoveset);
            // System.out.println(this.currentMoveset);
            for (int i = 0; i < this.currentMoveset.size(); i++) {
                tempMoveset.push(this.currentMoveset.pop());
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < this.currentMoveset.size(); j++) {
                finalMoveset.push(tempMoveset.pop());
            }
            // System.out.println(finalMoveset);
            this.currentMoveset = finalMoveset;
        }
    }
```

This method does work somewhat effectively however by using a thread instead of the main thread it seems that the AI often gets out of sync with its own move set resulting in it moving through walls. I know this to be a problem with my threaded implementation as when run in the main thread my A* implementation will always avoid obstacles correctly.

My question is whether this is the right way to go about reducing frame drops for AI path finding and if so how I might be going wrong with this implementation. One of the main reasons I was unable to do it in the main thread is that the map and the obstacles must be regenerated for each search so that previous searches don't effect the Nodes within the map causing later searches to choose non-optimal paths. My implementation uses a 2D-array of Node objects to represent the map but I found no easy way to deep-copy such an array correctly to allow me to not have to regenerate the map with each search. If I were able to do this I might be able to not have to used threading at all. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

I realised that by using a for loop to go through stacks based upon a stacks size then editing it within it it would cause the loop to only get half of them moves in a given stack resulting in a mis-match between the position of the AI and its move-set by changing loops such as;

```
for (int i = 0; i < this.currentMoveset.size(); i++) {
                tempMoveset.push(this.currentMoveset.pop());
            }
```

To this :

```
while(!this.currentMoveset.isEmpty()) {
                tempMoveset.push(this.currentMoveset.pop());
            }
```

I was able to solve my issues with incorrect moves.

Comment: Rather than copying the map, writing on top of it, and discarding... Perhaps you should create an array that overlays the map. Write on the array, read from the map itself. There will be no race conditions if each search has its own array. Additionally, does the AI need to be perfect in a fighting game? Don't calculate the whole path, just calculate a path to a marginally closer location to the player. If you have many enemies, use a flow field to guide them. Calculate the field every few frames, then the enemies just need to read the direction it tells them to move.

Comment: When they get closer and have line of sight, you can use a better AI. Do you use a simple AI when there's no path available? If so it would explain what's happening; your thread doesn't make paths fast enough so the AI defaults to stupid behaviour like trying to go through walls.

Comment: Thanks for the advice I realised I made a basic mistake when merging my move sets resulting in the move sets being out of sync with the actual position

Comment: Glad to hear it! If you have a moment, feel free to explain the mistake in detail by answering your question, and then edit your question's title to help others find it easier.